# Nil param in conditional version Carrierwave + Cloudinary Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, carrierwave, cloudinary

I am having uploading problem using carrierwave and cloudinary on heroku platform in production. Specifically in conditional versioning. Uploading occurs seamlessly to cloudinary, but in generation the version the error occurs.

See my very simple uploader class bellow:

```
class MediaAlbumUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  if Rails.env.production?
    include Cloudinary::CarrierWave
    # storage :fog
  else
    storage :file

    def store_dir
      "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
    end
  end

  version :thumb, if: :image? do
    process resize_and_pad: [450, 300]
  end

  def extension_whitelist
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end

  protected
    def image?(new_file)
      new_file.content_type.start_with? 'image'
    end
end
```

In the verification **image?** the param new_file is nil, look the error:

> NoMethodError (undefined method `content_type' for nil:NilClass)

The has extract with heroku logs -t

Remember, uploading to cloudinary occurs without problems so the new_file should not be null.

Comment: So I used google cloud service with the same code and had no problem. I have no idea of the problem with cloudinary. Maybe using without the carrierwave will work.